# Django sum all related objects of a filtered QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, json-rpc

What I would like to do in psuedo code is:

```
def import_transaction_deposit_crypto(Importer):
    logger = get_nexchange_logger(__name__, True, True)
    existent_addresses = Address.objects.filter(
        currency__is_crypto=True,
        type=Address.DEPOSIT,
        currency__wallet__in=Importer.RELATED_NODES

    ).tx_to_set.count()
```

Example value of importer:

```
class LitecoinTxImporter:
    RELATED_NODES = 'ltc_rpc_1'
```

`tx_to` is a related_field (reverse relation):

```
class Address(BtcBase, SoftDeletableModel):
    address_to = models.ForeignKey('core.Address',
                                   related_name='txs_to')
```

The idea is to count all 'already imported' transactions that belong to a **specific** RPC node (wallet), in order to feed it to the `from` parameter of the `listtransactions` RPC endpoint (generally speaking, for pagination purposes).

Comment: Then why is the title of your post "sum all" if you want to count?

Answer (score 2):

This is [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) with a perfectly matching example:

```
# Build an annotated queryset
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> q = Book.objects.annotate(Count('authors'))
# Interrogate the first object in the queryset
>>> q[0]
<Book: The Definitive Guide to Django>
>>> q[0].authors__count
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start the filtering from `Address`:

`Adress.objects.filter(address_to__curency__is_crpyto=True, ...).count()`

Comment: Good idea, I am looking for tx though

Comment: what do you mean?